# Cypress: Import line under commands.ts causes errors

Tags: typescript, testing, automated-tests, cypress

When I add imports into the `commands.ts`, then I get errors by running the tests.

commands.ts

```
import 'cypress-localstorage-commands';

/* eslint-disable */
declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Chainable<Subject = any> {
     commandA();
     commandB();
     commandC();
  }
}
```

Error:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'cypress-localstorage-commands'
> in 'C:...\cypress\support\commands\commands' resolve
> 'cypress-localstorage-commands' in 'C:...\cypress\support\commands'
> Parsed request is a module  using description file:
> C:...\angular\package.json (relative path:
> ./cypress/support/commands)
> Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration

Comment: Could you maybe improve your question by adding details regarding the cypress-localstorage-commands module you try to import? In general though, I can say that we have also been using Cypress for a while now and imports in commands.ts always resulted in issues, either the tests break or IntelliSense for Custom Commands stopped working. Depending on the contents of your module, I would consider moving these directly to the commands.ts.

Comment: Link to cypress-localstorage-commands: https://github.com/javierbrea/cypress-localstorage-commands

The test cases, that use the commands from this modul are working. The remaining test after running in the test runner get an error (see above)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution of my import error was to add 'global' to commands.ts.

```
import cypress-localstorage-commands';
/* eslint-disable */
declare global{
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable<Subject = any> {
       commandA();
       commandB();
       commandC();
    }
  }
}
```